# Time series interpolation to create new data points

Tags: python, interpolation, accelerometer, gyroscope

I have data from smarthphone sensors (i.e. accelerometer and gyroscope). However evry time i record accelerometer gives more data points than gyroscope. In order to convert my time series I need to interpolate the shortest and expand it to the length of the longest. I checked a lot of examples about interpolation but i have found nothing to compare two time series. Any ideas?
Here is an example of my data. I need to cread data points in the second time series an convert it from `70` to `182 data points`

```
Accelerometer Data
       x         y         z          timestamp
0  0.912956 -1.027331 -0.645289     1649001565984
1 -0.012292 -1.145001  0.092476     1649001565850
2  1.510848 -0.709704 -0.043249     1649001565721
3  1.231071  1.419836  0.576115     1649001565588
4  0.135664  0.981124  0.405955     1649001565457

(182, 4)
```

```
Gyroscope data
       x         y         z           timestamp
0  1.701820  1.780314 -2.289303     1649001535697
1  3.346221 -1.757866 -2.721783     1649001535563
2 -0.488831  0.080937 -1.201842     1649001535430
3 -0.334897  0.774860  0.214102     1649001535282
4 -1.786270 -0.511585  2.848075     1649001535147
(70, 4)
```

[image: Accelerometer data]

[image: Gyroscope data]

Comment: In what way timeseries is different from numbers?

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I am not sure i undestand what you mean. I have to create 112 data pointes to mathch the long time series based on dataframe timestamp. The plots are based on number of points and not timestamp. Did i help?